# How to show top to bottom leaks in my path

Tags: java, depth-first-search, union-find

I used the percolation class from the [algs4.jar](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/) library, where you can simulate a whole labyrinth  and see where the leaks are. I want to show the leaks that are from top to bottom, but now I get to see all of the leaks.

**Does anyone know how I can see only the leaks that are percolations?**

I thought maybe using dfs from the **flow** method in de Percolation.java class, and say something like only show when index i in rows is maxlength and marked but I don't really know how to say that, because I am not sure if this statement will show the entire leak of just the max length leak.

code I run **AssignmentTwo.java**:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

public class AssignmentTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n      = 500;
        double p   = 0.60;
        int trials = 20;

        // repeatedly created n-by-n matrices and display them using standard draw
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
            boolean[][] open = Percolation.random(n, p);
            StdDraw.clear();
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.PINK);
            Percolation.show(open, false);
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
            boolean[][] full = Percolation.flow(open);
            Percolation.show(full, true);
            StdDraw.show();
            StdDraw.pause(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the **Percolation.java** class:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdArrayIO;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

public class Percolation {

    // given an n-by-n matrix of open sites, return an n-by-n matrix
    // of sites reachable from the top
    public static boolean[][] flow(boolean[][] isOpen) {
        int n = isOpen.length;
        boolean[][] isFull = new boolean[n][n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            flow(isOpen, isFull, 0, j);
        }
        return isFull;
    }

    // determine set of full sites using depth first search
    public static void flow(boolean[][] isOpen, boolean[][] isFull, int i, int j) {
        int n = isOpen.length;

        // base cases
        if (i < 0 || i >= n) return;    // invalid row
        if (j < 0 || j >= n) return;    // invalid column
        if (!isOpen[i][j]) return;      // not an open site
        if (isFull[i][j]) return;       // already marked as full

        // mark i-j as full
        isFull[i][j] = true;

        flow(isOpen, isFull, i+1, j);   // down
        flow(isOpen, isFull, i, j+1);   // right
        flow(isOpen, isFull, i, j-1);   // left
        flow(isOpen, isFull, i-1, j);   // up
    }


    // does the system percolate?
    public static boolean percolates(boolean[][] isOpen) {
        int n = isOpen.length;
        boolean[][] isFull = flow(isOpen);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (isFull[n-1][j]) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // draw the n-by-n boolean matrix to standard draw
    public static void show(boolean[][] a, boolean which) {
        int n = a.length;
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1, n);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (a[i][j] == which)
                    StdDraw.filledSquare(j, n-i-1, 0.5);
    }

    // return a random n-by-n boolean matrix, where each entry is
    // true with probability p
    public static boolean[][] random(int n, double p) {
        boolean[][] a = new boolean[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                a[i][j] = StdRandom.bernoulli(p);
        return a;
    }

    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[][] isOpen = StdArrayIO.readBoolean2D();
        StdArrayIO.print(flow(isOpen));
        StdOut.println(percolates(isOpen));
    }

}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Are you referring to this [algs4.jar](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/) file?

Comment: @Abra yes, I added this jar file in my IntelliJ dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that disabling double buffering will get you the result you want:

```
public class AssignmentTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n      = 500;
        double p   = 0.60;

        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        boolean[][] open = Percolation.random(n, p);
        StdDraw.clear();
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.PINK);
        Percolation.show(open, false);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
        StdDraw.show();
        StdDraw.disableDoubleBuffering();
         boolean[][] full = Percolation.flow(open);
         Percolation.show(full, true);
    }
}
```

[image]